# Postgres weird PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: on value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

While executing a simple select - where operation using activerecord execute,

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select * from spree_variants where sku = "1SB-E4196-00";')
```

I got this error:

```
from /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2@cboparts/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `exec'
Caused by PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "1SB-E4196-00" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from spree_variants where sku = "1SB-E4196-00";
```

Why it is considering `"1SB-E4196-00"` as a column but not SKU? The error seems misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because PostgreSQL expects strings to be bounded in [single quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS). While [double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) have a different meaning:

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an identifier, never a key word.

That means if the following query should work:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
  "select * from spree_variants where sku = '1SB-E4196-00';"
)
```

Btw you if you are using Rails and have a `SpreeVariant` model then you can see in the console how Rails formats and escapes the query like this:

```
puts SpreeVariant.where(sku: '1SB-E4196-00').to_sql
```